# Update google cloud compute engine VM via rest api

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to update the container image for a google cloud compute engine VM using googleapis rest api ?

the only method I found is via `gcloud` cli

```
gcloud compute instances update-container [INSTANCE_NAME] --container-image gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG]
```

Comment: Add the command line flag `--log-http`. You can then review the APIs the command calls. I am ***guessing*** that you must update a Docker setting or command (e.g. pull image) or change instance metadata.